# Encrypt and Decrypt Files with Symmetric Algorithms

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, encryption-symmetric

i want to encrypt and decrypt files using Symmetric Algorithms. for small file there is no issue but if our file is large for example (100 mb, 1 GB, 5 GB,...) simple codes does not work and We have to use different methods to solve this problem.
i used ChatGPT to Create a Encrypt and Decrypt Methods, Encrypt Method works fine and read large file without issues and encrypt and write encryped file on disk. but when i want to decrypt file, i get Com Exception in CryptographicEngine.Decrypt line.
i tested for a tiny 3 kb Text file and issue exist.
so i found that if encrypting file goes wrong decryption will be failed.
so what is wrong with my encrypt method? how to fix this?

```
public static async Task EncryptFileAsync(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    var provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
    var keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);
    var iv = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);

    var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
    const int bufferSize = 4096; // Choose an appropriate buffer size

    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(inputFile);

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        using (IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                {
                    while (stream.Position < stream.Size)
                    {
                        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                        uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(bufferSize);

                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            // Convert the buffer to IBuffer
                            IBuffer buffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(bytesRead);
                            IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffer, iv);
                            var byteArray = bufferEncrypt.ToArray();

                            await fs.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                            // Your processing logic with the IBuffer goes here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Break the loop if no more bytes can be read
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save the key and iv for later decryption
    SaveKeyAndIV(keyMaterial, iv);
}

public static async Task DecryptFileAsync(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    // Load the key and iv used for encryption
    var (keyMaterial, iv) = LoadKeyAndIV();

    var provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
    var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
    const int bufferSize = 4096; // Choose an appropriate buffer size

    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(inputFile);

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        using (IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
        {
            using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                {
                    while (stream.Position < stream.Size)
                    {
                        dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                        uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(bufferSize);

                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            // Convert the buffer to IBuffer
                            IBuffer buffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(bytesRead);
                            IBuffer bufferDecrypt = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, buffer, iv);

                            // Convert the decrypted buffer to byte array
                            var decryptedBytes = bufferDecrypt.ToArray();

                            await fs.WriteAsync(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);

                            // Your processing logic with the decrypted data goes here
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Break the loop if no more bytes can be read
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should terminate or answer or react wih comments to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723009/encrypt-decrypt-file-with-symmetric-algo-in-winui-uwp-app before reposting a similar one

Comment: @PowerCode What if Simon doesn't have the specific knowledge to answer the question (like myself) but is trying to be helpful and guide you in the ways of [so]. Besides, having a single question makes it easier for you to maintain the discussion.

Comment: 2  comments: it's unusual to see the key and IV saved/restored together. The IV is usually in the same channel as the cipher text (but in the clear). They key is usually managed in a separate fashion completely. I don't see any calls to `Flush` on your streams. Sometimes unflushed streams work (because of buffer behavior) other times, things fail at the worst time

Answer (score 0):

When you put 'try catch blocks' around parts of code, you can find out more clearly where errors are coming from. This is [how they work in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling).

For the encription method:

```
public static async Task EncryptFileAsync(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    try
    {
        var provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);
        var iv = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(provider.BlockLength);

        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        const int bufferSize = 4096; // Choose an appropriate buffer size

        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(inputFile);

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                    {
                        while (stream.Position < stream.Size)
                        {
                            dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                            uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(bufferSize);

                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                IBuffer buffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(bytesRead);
                                IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffer, iv);
                                var byteArray = bufferEncrypt.ToArray();

                                await fs.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        SaveKeyAndIV(keyMaterial, iv);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        Console.WriteLine($"Encryption failed with exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

For the decryption method:

```
public static async Task DecryptFileAsync(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    try
    {
        var (keyMaterial, iv) = LoadKeyAndIV();

        var provider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        const int bufferSize = 4096; // Choose an appropriate buffer size

        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(inputFile);

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                    {
                        while (stream.Position < stream.Size)
                        {
                            dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                            uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(bufferSize);

                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                IBuffer buffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(bytesRead);
                                IBuffer bufferDecrypt = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, buffer, iv);
                                var decryptedBytes = bufferDecrypt.ToArray();

                                await fs.WriteAsync(decryptedBytes, 0, decryptedBytes.Length);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        Console.WriteLine($"Decryption failed with exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: winui does not care about try/catch and give us a big Com exception

Comment: when you talk to people like to SimonMourier you turn everything sour for everyone, including yourself